# Compiler: is implicit type conversion considered in parsing or semantic analysis?

Tags: parsing, compilation, compiler-construction, clang, semantic-analysis

In my understanding implicit conversion is done in semantic analysis, but clang AST command `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only file.cpp` produces type conversion information in AST, like these two:

> ...
> `- ImplicitCastExpr 0x7fdc27050558 <col:14> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
> ...
>
> ...
> ImplicitCastExpr 0x7f878884c2d0 <col:19> 'unsigned int' <IntegralCast>
> ...

hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit type conversion usually occurs in the semantic analysis(more specifically type checking) of a compiler but some can happen in the parsing to make a simpler AST (converting literals to their values directly and so on).

If you look specifcally at the command option you used we see that it means

> -fsyntax-only
>    Run the preprocessor, parser and type checking stages.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html

so we see that we expect type information(which requires implicit conversion) to be outputted.

NOTE: I may be unclear, but type checking is just a stage of semantic analysis.